# Create new instance of object with methods

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have some trouble with OnPush change detection strategy.

I have class

```
class Item {
  private name;
  private _valid;

  public set valid(valid) {
    this._valid = valid;
  }

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  getName() {
     return this.name;    
  }
}
```

In my component I create new instance of item via "new" operator

```
this.item = new Item('Joe');
```

and pass it into child component which use OnPush strategy too.

```
<child [item]=item></child>
```

I some cases I change e.g. valid property

```
this.item.valid = false;
```

And now I should create new instance of object to fire NgOnChanges mehtod in child component.

But I don't understood, how to do it right way.

If I do `this.item = {...this.item}` , then all methods of item are lost.

If I do `this.item = Object.create(this.item)` I have empty object and all methods and properties are in prototype. And if I do this action many times chain of prototypes will increase each time by one.

Or only one way is - create every time new instance of Item?

Maybe someone can show me right way?

Comment: maybe it's a TYPO .. but you have to use 3 DOTS .. so {...this.item}

Comment: Yea, sorry this typo

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the class to the child component and call the functions in you child component, without needing to create a new instance every time.
You need to export the class if used in own .ts file.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() item: Item;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
<p>{{item.getName()}}</p>
```

Parent Component:

```
<child [item]="item"></child>
```

I created a simple example to show you the way of doing it correctly: https://plnkr.co/edit/k4qBLgXxlaNkUgqU9cH5?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much for affort, but problem is, when I add Onpush changedetection strategy to AppComponent and change item.name in parent component inside setTimeout, changes are not applied, because for children input Item is the same. Please see plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/dlwnh9r7psvpF7RJ3Dh8?p=preview